# Can I develop Java servlet using eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt

I am currently using the Android developer Tools platform to develop android code, downloaded from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Now i want to develop Java servlets as well for my server side app and generate the WAR file. As i understand it, I can't use the ADT to develop servlets. **Since i think it is basically an Eclipse IDE with the ADT plugin, can i simply install another plugin so that it supports servlet development? If yes, how do i do that exactly? Or do i need to install another eclipse?** I am a complete newbie to Eclipse and Java, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Web Tools Platform.  Be sure to find out which version of the Eclipse Platform you're already using first. http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Comment: Thanks, that should work. In the interim, I had downloaded and installed the eclipse for Java EE from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr. That works for me since i get the latest Kepler release, while the ADT i had was based on the Juno release of the eclipse platform.